# jQuery append a comment after it's successfully submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to Ajax submit a comment and append it after the submission form when the AJAX status is successful. However it's not working correctly.

HTML:

```
<div class="reply_form_div">
<textarea  name='reply' type='text' class="form-control reply" rows="3" ></textarea>
<button type="submit" STYLE="align: right;" class="btn btn-info reply_button yGreenButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function()
{
  $('.reply_button').click(function(){

  var reply = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();

  $.ajax({ 
          type:"POST",
          url: base_url + "interview/reply_upload",
          data:{reply: reply}, 
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data,status){
            if(data.state == 'succ')
            {
              this_a.html('Success');
              $(this).parent().append("<b>Hello world!</b>");
            }
            else
            {
              this_a.html('fail');  
            }
      }
      });
   });
}):
```

The server end language is working correctly, and I can see the append information if I place it outside the ajax brackets.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you're using `this` in several locations where it doesn't mean anything and if it did, would mean varying things.

Comment: I have a feeling 'this' may be getting overwritten inside the ajax request, if you try use the '.reply_button' selector does it work?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `$(this)` refers to the AJAX response when inside of a callback. In this case, you need to cache a reference to the original element that fired the click event.

```
$('.reply_button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
```

Now you can perform the append in the success using the cached reference defined above.

```
$this.parent().append("<b>Hello world!</b>");
```